# wicket form event onsubmit not working at V6.X

Tags: ajax, wicket

I have a page like this.

**HTML**

```
<form wicket:id="form" onsubmit="alert('form submit')">

 <input type="text" name="name">

 <!-- Wicket1.5.X form.onsubmit working -->
 <!-- Wicket6.X form.onsubmit can not work -->
 <input wicket:id="ajaxFallbackButton" type="submit">

 <!-- form.onsubmit works fine -->
 <input wicket:id="submitBtn" type="submit">

</form>
```

**Java**

```
    Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("form");
    form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(form);

    AjaxFallbackButton ajaxFallbackButton = new AjaxFallbackButton("ajaxFallbackButton", new Model<String>("AjaxFallbackButton"), form) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            System.out.println("ajaxFallbackButton onSubmit");
        }
    };
    form.add(ajaxFallbackButton);

    Button button = new Button("submitBtn", new Model<String>("Button"));
    form.add(button);
```

Why the event of form onsubmit defined int the html can not work when I used **Wicket V6.X**?

---

Thanks for **[svenmeier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1041336/svenmeier)**, I fixed it by override the `AjaxFallbackButton.updateAjaxAttributes` method.

```
    @Override
protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
    super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);

    AjaxCallListener ajaxCallListener = new AjaxCallListener();
    ajaxCallListener.onPrecondition("alert('form submit')");
    attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(ajaxCallListener);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wicket 6 uses JavaScript event handlers, so your inline JavaScript is not executed.

Read here for further explanation and solutions:

[Wicket AjaxButton and javascript condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064873/wicket-ajaxbutton-and-javascript-condition)

Comment: Thanks a lot, haha